# How long before I can re-enter the US on a B visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens

I'm a 24 year-old Australian traveller.
I just spent a full 6 months in the US, mostly around LA. I stayed the full length of my allowed stay on a B2 tourist visa. I'd never ever been the States before!

I'm now back in Australia and wondering if I should wait another 6 months before coming to the US. I understand that is the general suggested guideline and that there are no real rules. I met a girl I really like there and would love to see her again. I'm not sure if anyone has any experience telling that to immigration on their next arrival.

Comment: One thing that the immigration inspector will want to know is how you can afford to spend so much time in the US without working in the US.  The US (in contrast to Canada) does not permit visitors in B-2 status to work remotely for a foreign employer.  Another thing that people sometimes overlook is US tax law.  If you spend more than 183 days in the US in one year, you have to worry about qualifying as a resident under US tax law, in which case your worldwide income is subject to taxation.

Comment: How long is your visa valid for and is it multiple entry? Also as an Australian why did you decide to get a visa for the US? Was it to be able to stay 6 months, or was there another reason you needed one?

Comment: A typical rule of thumb is to spend at least as much time in your home country (or the country to which you intend and have the right to return to) as elsewhere. As others have said, such a long visit begs the question of how you supported yourself. Perhaps you could plan for your gf to visit you? Reciprocal visits help establish the validity of a relationship in the eyes of an ECO

Answer (score 4):

There is no set time you must wait between visits. You could, in theory, return the day after you left, and be admitted again. The problem is that you have to convince the CBP agent that you are not trying to live or work in the US and are simply visiting. This becomes much more difficult when you don't spend much time outside the US...